# Is there a way to change the Header key to X-API-Authorization instead of Authorization when passing token for authenticating the Laravel API's?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, header

I am using Laravel inbuilt Bearer token for API authentication. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/api-authentication#passing-tokens-in-requests

```
$response = $client->request('POST', '/api/user', [
    'headers' => [
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$token,
        'Accept' => 'application/json',
    ],
]);
```

I would like to change the `Authorization` header to `X-API-Authorization` since we already have a legacy authentication in place which use this header `Authorization`, which I have no control over.

Does Laravel provide over-riding this inbuilt functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The header key `Authorization` seems to be [hardcoded](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/91553d8ed15f398b29c45e3241ae36da1811174c/src/Illuminate/Http/Concerns/InteractsWithInput.php#L53) in laravel. Your best bet is, creating a new Authentication guard by extending the Laravel [TokenGuard](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Auth/TokenGuard.php), and overriding the `getTokenForRequest` method to use your custom header key.

See - https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication#adding-custom-guards